# beautiful soup scraping table after logging in a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I have a piece of python code which logs me into a website. I am trying to extract the data of a particular table, I'm getting errors and I'm not sure how to resolve it after searching online.

Here is my code written in my `f.py` file:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import cookielib
import requests

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open("http://kingmedia.tv/home")

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['vb_login_username'] = 'abcde'
br.form['vb_login_password'] = '12345'
br.submit()

a = br.response().read()


url = br.open("http://kingmedia.tv/home/forumdisplay.php?f=2").read()

print (url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')
for table in soup.select('table#tborder tr')[1:]:
    cell = table.select_one('td').get_text(strip=True)
    print(cell)
```

`print (url)` gives me the HTML data of the url which I have shown below from which I want to extract the table data. The table data that I am interested in is *`table class="tborder"`*

**Update: 07/05/2021**

Using `soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')` as suggested by @Code-Apprentice, I am able to get the desired data. However I am struggling to obtain it fully.

I need this table [image] and the source code from the link is the following:

```
<td class="alt1" width="100%"><div><font size="2"><div>

    <a href="calendar.php?do=getinfo&amp;day=2021-5-7&amp;e=18116&amp;c=1">Live: EPL - Leicester v Newcastle (CH3)</a>: 05/07/21 to 05/07/21

</div><div>

    <a href="calendar.php?do=getinfo&amp;day=2021-5-8&amp;e=18121&amp;c=1">Live: EPL - Liverpool v Southampton (CH3)</a>: 05/08/21 to 05/08/21

</div><div>

    <a href="calendar.php?do=getinfo&amp;day=2021-5-8&amp;e=18123&amp;c=1">Live: UFC PreLims (CH2)</a>: 05/08/21 to 05/08/21

</div><div>

    <a href="calendar.php?do=getinfo&amp;day=2021-5-8&amp;e=18124&amp;c=1">Live: UFC - Sandhagen v Dillashaw (CH2)</a>: 05/08/21 to 05/09/21

</div><div>

    <a href="calendar.php?do=getinfo&amp;day=2021-5-8&amp;e=18120&amp;c=1">Live: EPL - Man City v Chelsea (CH3)</a>: 05/08/21 to 05/08/21

</div><div>

    <a href="calendar.php?do=getinfo&amp;day=2021-5-8&amp;e=18122&amp;c=1">Live: La Liga - Barcelona v Atletico Madrid (CH6)(beIn)</a>: 05/08/21 to 05/08/21

</div><div>

    <a href="calendar.php?do=getinfo&amp;day=2021-5-8&amp;e=18118&amp;c=1">Live: EPL - Leeds v Tottenham (CH3)</a>: 05/08/21 to 05/08/21

</div><div>

    <a href="calendar.php?do=getinfo&amp;day=2021-5-8&amp;e=18125&amp;c=1">Live: F1 Qualifying (CH2)</a>: 05/08/21 to 05/08/21

</div><div>

    <a href="calendar.php?do=getinfo&amp;day=2021-5-8&amp;e=18119&amp;c=1">Live: EPL - Sheff Utd v Crystal Palace (CH3)</a>: 05/08/21 to 05/08/21

</div></font><br>View More Detailed Calendar <a href="/home/calendar.php">HERE</a></div></td>
```

Comment: @KunduK can you help please ?

Comment: @Selçuk can you please help?

Comment: @jxpython can you please help?

Comment: dear Ahmed - the login seems to work with your piece of code - thanks for sharing this idea with mechanize.  BTW - for getting more insights and examples regarding bs4 and vbulletin cf here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972690/beautifulsoup-scraping-a-forum-page

Comment: What is the contents of the `url` variable? Is it really a URL? Furthermore, why are you mixing `mechanize` and `requests`? Pick one HTTP library and stick to it.

Comment: Furthermore, why are you reading the response from one request then using it as the URL for another request? This is unlikely to work. I suggest continuing with `mechanize` since it will have the logged in state, but `requests` won't.

Comment: It's important to name your objects according to what they are, [follow standard conventions](https://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/browser_api.html). Your `url` is not an URL! When you `br.open()` an url you get a [`mechanize.Response` object](https://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/browser_api.html#the-response) and then when you `.read()` that response, you get HTML. I'd name that variable `html` or something. I wouldn't call your output 'url data', I'd just call it 'the HTML from the response'.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I did manage to sort it out. However I am not able to obtain the desired data. I have updated my question in relation to this. Can you please have a look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
url = br.open("http://kingmedia.tv/home/forumdisplay.php?f=2").read()

print (url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')
```

This looks very suspicious. You are reading the content of one HTTP response then using it as the URL for another request. Instead, just parse the content of the first request with beautiful soup:

```
content = br.open("http://kingmedia.tv/home/forumdisplay.php?f=2").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
```

First, I renamed `url` to `content` to reflect what the variable actual represents. Second, I use `content` directly in the creation of the `BeautifulSoup` object.

Disclaimer: this still might not be exactly correct, but it should get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I am getting somewhere now. I am now trying to extract the data from the table but somehow not getting it right. I have updated the question to show what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Ahmed.B Since my answer solves your initial problem, you should accept the answer and then post a new question for your next issue. Include a link to this question in the new one for additional context.

Comment: I cannot post anymore questions as my account is blocked for some reason. I will mark your answer as the one. I am getting byte objects as I got encode('utf') and I tried to use decode but it throws an error.